# Accessing a VC++ Dll from C# (compact framework)

Tags: c#, c++, dll, compact-framework

I'm trying to compile a DLL in vc++ and use it in C# for Smart Device.
Is it possible and how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use PInvoke, and you probably need to expose the call from your unmanaged dll as extern "C". [Have a look here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa446536.aspx). What you have to consider is that generally you *can't* use the classes you created in your C++ dll *directly*, but you need some `extern "C"` facade inside the C++ dll that helps you to interoperate. In order to ensure exporting the entry points needed from the dll you should ensure proper export is done: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3y1sfaz2.aspx. As an helpful tool to discover what entry points the dll actually export you can use dumpbin. I never used it on compact framework, but this blog seems talk about it: http://geekswithblogs.net/BruceEitman/archive/2009/02/25/windows-ce-dumpbin.aspx. Basically with dumpbin you can have a drop of the names exposed from the dll to help you in PInvoke declaration.

Comment: Hehe, exactly the same article! But I beat you by a minute. :-P

Comment: Thanks. I think it's the way to go, but I get exception "Can't find an Entry Point 'fnDLLTest' in a PInvoke DLL 'dlltest.dll'". I think the extern "C" is the problem, but couldn't figure how to do that.

Comment: having just extern "C" is rquired but not enougth. You should also exports the entry points from the dll. I extended the reply with another link on how to export

Comment: The problem was that the DLL was not correctly deployed to the emulator. The program simply used an incorrect version of the DLL. I had to copy it manually. Thanks for the information.

Comment: I had to do some tricks to export my classes: I created C functions for create/destroy/any methods of the class, and implemented a system similar to windows handles.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is.
Look at [P/Invoke](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa446536.aspx).